# How to make movieclips respond to mouse events with invisible button on top

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a banner with big invisible button covering the stage and underneath it I have movieclips which must respond to mouse events. But I can't get through invisible button. I only get button events and cant interact with movieclips underneath it. Here's simple code:

```
invisibleBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onTopClick);
bottomMc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onBottomOver);

function onTopClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
    trace("top - click");
}

function onBottomOver(e:MouseEvent):void{
    trace("bottom - over");
}
```

I never get bottomMc MouseEvent... any thoughts? 
Thanks!

Comment: Search the mouseEnabled and mouseChildren properties in the docs.

Comment: I want both to be mouse enabled - so invisibleBtn.mouseEnabled = false, wont work, because I need it to receive click events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only thing that you can done with this is to make invisibleBtn disable and put click event on movieclip instead of button.

so, it should like this.

```
invisibleBtn.mouseEnable=false;
invisibleBtn.mouseChildren =false;

bottomMc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onTopClick);
bottomMc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onBottomOver);

function onTopClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
    trace("top - click");
}

function onBottomOver(e:MouseEvent):void{
    trace("bottom - over");
}
```

so, it will take event for movieclip

Comment: well that's not really an option, because there are several movieclips underneath - some have mouse events and some don't - that would mean that I would have to add click events to all movie clips on different frames - and that's just too much :)

Comment: it's just simple banner scenario - with invisible button on top and  movieclips underneath it - some respond to mouse events, some not - some are just animations and background - adding click events to all of them doesn't seem the right way...

Comment: Then do one thing, Instead of apply Click Event to Movieclip, Apply Click Event To Stage.so, you get same Functionality as with Invisible button and movieclip can also get MouseEvent.

Comment: also if designer adds more movieclips or deletes some - i would have to write code each time the changes are made...

Comment: yep thats what I did :), thnks

Comment: it's my pleasure.im happy to help u

Answer (score 0):

You have a main button which on click will open new page, and at the same time you want the user interaction to be happening with other objects? RETHINK the approach.

You have 2 solutions:

1.Show the `invisibleBtn` only when no more user interaction is available.

2.Or use this function:

```
getObjectsUnderPoint ( new Point ( stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY ) );
```

put this line in EnterFrame handle, then you wil be getting all object as an Array, there you can check the names of the objects, and decide is now you are `onBottomOver` or `onBottomOut` because all the time it will be onver the invisibleBtn which is active.

Comment: naaah.. thats too much for such a simple thing :), thnks though.. well I got rid of the invisible button and recoded like this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onTopClick); and thats exactly what I need - all movieclips get their events and onTopClick works too. So no point of using invisible button :)

Comment: so it almost the same as you would put the invisibleB to the background. :)

Answer (score 0):

recommend having a single button for that space... and when clicked keep track if the movieclip is visible... if it is then do whatever operation you need as if the movieclip was clicked as well

Answer (score 0):

check if bottomMc is in the front

or try this:

```
this.setChildIndex(bottomMc,this.numChildren-1);
```